# How do you make steam see my system as 64 bit system on PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, games, steam, playonlinux

I don't need a 64 bit version of Steam. I just need Steam to see my system as a 64 bit system inside of PlayOnLinux.

I can only make it see it as a 32 bit version, with which games that require a 64 bit system won't work.

My actual computer is a 64 bit computer but when I install Steam on PlayOnLinux, it recognises it as a 32 system.

When I install other programs they run as a 64 bit system but for some reason I can't get Steam to work in the same way.

I have tried many things. I have Ubuntu 16.10 and wine 1.6.2 and playonlinux 4.2.10.

Anyone knows what I should do?

Comment: Why don't you use a Linux version of Steam? Why install it with playonlinux?

Comment: ^ to play windows games, such as INSIDE

Answer (score 6):

When I installed it, I used the default Steam on PlayOnLinux, but this sets up a 32bit Wine for it.

Instead, when you use PlayOnLinux's "Install a program" feature, you have to click on the "Install non-listed program" and go through the entire setup.

When it asks you if you want 32 bit or 64 bit, select 64. Then when it asks you for the setup file, select the `SteamSetup.exe` file from the Steam website (for windows). Install everything and then check in the steam settings if you have a 64 bit windows system.